Excel formula to search for a matching word in a word string across multiple cells
I have two columns, one (A) contains ~1000 account names from one database, second one (B) ~70000 account names from another database. These names may match, but no necessarily. Sometimes only one word will be matching.
I need a formula that will:

take the name (or separate words) from column 1
search across column 2 for any matching WORD (not the full name! this would not be sufficient)
If a match exists, put the content of column A in column C (next to matching entry in column B). If not possible, I can live with Yes/No, True/False.

So it should look like this:



Column A
Column B
Column C




Daimler AG
Plastiques Maghreb
False


Ege Plastik
Daimler AG
Daimler AG


Aiplast, S.L
Veritex B.V.
False


Adria Media Zagreb d.o.o
Meto International GmbH
False


Veri Berry Ltd
Savory Paper Ltd
False



Ege Plastik Ambalaj San ve Tic A.S.
Ege Plastik



Adria Media Zagreb
Adria Media Zagreb d.o.o



It is crucial that I get the results if - as shown above - only part of column B matches to cell in Column A. I am not even sure this can be done, but anything close will be helpful, too.
I liked how this works:
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*Daimler*"),"Found","Not found")

But in this case I would need to build this function separately for every cell from column A by replacing the text between asterisks.

Microsoft has a tool called fuzzy lookup that does this.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Great effort on making it clear! I've started with XLOOKUP, however, that doesn't give you the results on the specific place, but it looks something like =XLOOKUP("*"&A1:A5&"*",B1:B7,B1:B7,'"ALSE",2) ; the 2 at the end is the crucial part, combined with the "*" before and after the formula. Hope this gets you started.

Okay, so this is the best I came up with so far:
=XLOOKUP("*"&TEXTBEFORE(B25:B31," ")&"*",A25:A31,A25:A31,"False",2)

What it does:
"*"&TEXTBEFORE(B25:B31," ")&"*" gives you the first word before a 'space' of whatever is in row B, and adds asterix before and after;
A25:A31 is the list in which this word is searched, and the list that is returned;
"FALSE" is the result if nothing is found in the list;
2 activates the wildcard search;
Just adjust your ranges accordingly. Can't promise it's 100% failproof, but for the given data set it seems to work.

